# Match string with array of string in any order

Tags: javascript, arrays, match, string-matching

My input is a string, it may be the person's first name, last, combination, or even part of both, in specific order

```
Class {
    first = 'John'          //  just simple string
    last = 'Smith'          //  just simple string
    middle = 'Mark Bill'    //  this is often empty string, but may contain multiple, divided by spaces. ('' or 'Mark Bill')

    hasPresent(what){
        return true || false
    }
}
```

If user's input is 'John', our John's `hasPresent` method should return true
Other cases:

```
"input" => expected result

"Smith" => true
"mark" => true
"John Mark" => true
"hn mar" => true
"m" => true
" " => true

"John John" => false
"John Mark John" => false
"Jo Mark" => false
"John rk" => false
"n n n" => false
```

For better understanding, imagine, that you can order the person's names in any order, as long you use it only once. Then take input and match it with ˙indexOf˙ function. That is, why ˙"John rk"˙ is false, what ever hard you try, you can put together a string having ˙"john rk"˙ in this specific order. You can have ˙"John Mark"˙, but this won't match using ˙indexOf˙.

From our names we can match anything that match any of folowing strings

```
"John Smith Mark Bill","John Mark Smith Bill","John Bill Smith Mark","John Mark Smith Bill","John Smith Bill Mark", "John Mark Bill Smith" etc
```

I think, creating array with all names (first, last, and separated middle names) and matching against all possible combinations could be the way to go, but since this has to be done before, I would like to know if there is a better way.

If there isn't a better way, how to make all the possible combinations from the array with as little processing power as possible?

Comment: Why would `"John rk"` return `false`  ?

Comment: Take it as if you would do `indexOf` on `"Jonh Mark"`

Comment: Logic appear unclear , here. Not certain how `"hn mar"` could return `true`, while `"John rk"` could return `false` ? See OP at _"If user's input is 'John', our John's hasPresent method should return true"_ . How would `"rk"` negate `"John"` at beginning of input string ? , where both portions of string found in full name

Comment: As we strictly need to match the whole input to any order of person's names, there for `John ma` counts. It can be found in one piece without interruption if the order of his name is correct

Comment: Should input of any single character found in full name return `true` ?

Comment: If you type just the one? yes... even a space would return true, since it can be found between all names

Comment: @JuanBoca 's updated Answer should meet requirement, saving for case of `"John rk"`

Answer (score 2):

You can `concat` all the names, and for each word the user inputs, check if it is present on the string.

```
first = 'John';
last = 'Smith';
middle = 'Mark Bill';

searchStr = first + " " + middle + " " + last;

function hasPresent(param){
  searchLower = searchStr.toLowerCase();
  searchWords = param.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < searchWords.length; i++){
    index = searchLower.indexOf(searchWords[i])
    if (index == -1){
      return false;
    }
    searchLower = searchLower.substring(0,index) + searchLower.substring(index + searchWords[i].length, searchLower.length);
  }
  return true;
}
```

This will return true for your examples, and also for examples like "Joh Smi", but is case sensitive. You can adapt it to make it case insensitive if you need to.

Comment: This doesn't address problem of "n n n" as input string

Comment: Ok, I haven't seen that restriction before. I can adapt it. Should this return true for cases like `h h`,  `i i` or `Jo s`?

Comment: No thanks, it have to be continuous string, that is matched as "hn ma" for John Mark...

Comment: You can remove everything before each matched string, and then check for the next character or word. So it will return true for a case like "hn mar" but false for "mar hn". Does this work for you?

Comment: Well no since some people write `John Smith` and other `Smith Jonh`

Comment: Check the edited function. This works with your examples, except with `John rk`, that I agree with @guest271314 and it looks inconsistent to me

Comment: Much, better but this matches `"joh mark"` witch is incorect

Answer (score 0):

If you had a whole string you could just check `int indexOf(String str)` and if it is anything but -1 you know the string contains the words. If you wanted to turn an array into this long string, just do something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++)
{
    someStr += strArray[i];
}
```

then to check
    `someStr.indexOf("John");`

Comment: This is javascript no int ;) but got your point... the problem is, that I don't know in witch order is user using to filter peoples

Comment: Ah sorry, you had the label as 'Java' when I answered, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Edit, Updated

> Take it as if you would do `indexOf` on

```
var fullname = "John Mark Bill Smith";
var checkname = fullname.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
```

---

```js
var fullname = "John Mark Bill Smith";
var check = function(input) {
  return fullname.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) !== -1
}

console.log(check("Smith")
           , check("mark")
           , check("John Mark")
           , check("hn mar")
           , check("m")
           , check(" ")
           , check("John John")
           , check("John Mark John")
           , check("Jo Mark")
           , check("John rk")
           , check("n n n")
           )
```

Comment: In this case the user have to write one whole name, but interesting idea

Comment: @Akxe _"In this case the user have to write one whole name"_ Not certain interpret correctly ? If required input is user full name , `re` should  return `true`

Comment: The input can be for example "hn ma" as for John mark... sorry

Comment: @Akxe _"The input can be for example "hn ma" as for John mark."_ `"hn ma"` should return `false` , correct ? Is requirement to return `true` for any two characters in sequence found in input which match any portion of user name found in `Class` ?

Comment: `"hn ma"` should return `true` as user is searching for John Mark

Comment: @Akxe What is expected result if input is `"hn rk"` ?

Comment: `false` as `"hn rk"` isn't part of  `John Mark`

Comment: "rk" appear part of "Mark" , here ; last two letters. Is requirement that `true` returned only if input matches first two letters of first, middle, or last name ?

Comment: Yes but it is at end of mark, there for the invalid. Take it, as if `John Mark` was a string that you was calling `indexOf` on.

Comment: well if he type `"hn Smith"`, it should return true

Comment: @Akxe  _"well if he type "hn Smith", it should return true "_ ?  _"it have to be continuous string, that is matched "_ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313467/match-string-with-array-of-string-in-any-order?noredirect=1#comment54426228_33313601 .

Comment: Yes, but in any order

Comment: @Akxe if full name is string `"John Mark Bill Smith"` and  match `"hn Smith"` should return `true` ,  then should match , return `true` for `"John rk"` as well ?

Comment: You can order the words to make John Smith, but not to make John rkMa

Comment: @Akxe _"You can order the words to make John Smith"_ ? How ? , with this requirement _"it have to be continuous string, that is matched "_ ?

Comment: @Akxe `js` at post should return expected results for each case listed

Comment: Yes, but it wont match any different order that the one you given. `John Sm` should return true too. The user don't know in witch order to type the names go get the expected result. *I think, creating array with all names (first, last, and separated middle names) and matching against all possible combinations could be the way to go, but since this has to be done before, I would like to know if there is a better way.* We have to check against any single possible order

Comment: @Akxe If  requirement is to check for all possible combinations , would first need to create array or arrays of all possible combinations to check against.  When take into account comment _"it have to be continuous string, that is matched "_ . Perhaps take moment to refine actual Question , ask new Question including all required elements ? Presently, here, actual Question appear unclear ; at minimum different now than originally posted Question . Not certain how `"John Sm"` should return `true` while `"John rk"` should return `false`

Answer (score -2):

This is a beauty that makes it. I any order with as few cycles as possible.

```
hasPresent(what:string|number):boolean {
    if(isNumber(what)){
        return this.tel.hasPresent(what)
    }else{
        if (this.tel.hasPresent(what)) {
            return true
        }else{
            var query = what.toString().toLowerCase().split(' ')
            var possible = this.name.toLowerCase().trim().split(' ')
            if(query.length > possible.length){
                return false    //  No way this could be met
            }
            for (var i = possible.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                var possible2 = this.name.toLowerCase().trim().split(' ')
                if(possible[i].hasPresent(query[0])){
                    if (query.length==1){
                        return true
                    }
                    possible2.remove(possible[i])
                    for (var j = 1; j < query.length; j++){
                        var passed = false
                        for (var k = possible2.length - 1; k > 0; k--) {
                            if(possible2[k].indexOf(query[j]) == 0){
                                possible2.remove(possible2[k])
                                passed = true
                                break
                            }
                        }
                        if(!passed){
                            break
                        }
                    }
                    if(passed){
                        return true
                    }
                }
            }
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Side note:

```
Array.remove(object) - removes object for array
Array|String.hasPresent(needle) - shortcut for indexOf(needle) => 0
```

Comment: @JuanBoca this is the thing I wanted... if you have better name for this question, rename it, so it is helpful too :)

Comment: @guest271314 This is it, hope you will understand it now